# Style <select> the same as other form inputs

Tags: html

I have a contact form on my website (http://shopzuinig.nl/contact.html) and i want to put in this piece of HTML to let people choose between our two different locations:

```
   <select name="mydropdown">
    <option value="Restaurant/Kookstudio">Restaurant - Kookstudio Dell'Italia</option>
    <option value="Antipasti">Dell'Italia Antipasti</option>
    </select>
```

However, I don't know how to style it in the same way as the e-mail and name input. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

you can't. You can really only change the width, height and font-size. Maybe a few other little things. If you want a completely custom select you will need to fake it with JS or something.

Comment: I kept on searching and i found this article: http://www.kevinfremon.com/create-a-custom-drop-down-list-using-just-css/

Comment: thats a pretty good one! I suppose my answer is too skeptical. There will always be limitations with this but modern browsers seem to be OK. good find!